Unsupported binding form error when override the function with diff args
I am new to clojure. I am having the following protocol defined
(ns com.mycompany.protocols.tools)

(defprotocol Tool
   (test-ov [this] [this user-id]))

and I tried two implementation.
Impl way 1:
(ns com.mycompany.resources.tools

   (:require [com.mycompany.protocols.tools :as proto]))

(deftype MyTool [config]
   proto/Tool

 (test-ov
   ([this user-id]
       1111 )
 ([this]
   (test-ov this nil)))

......

Error I got
    LOAD FAILURE for com.mycompany.myservice.resources.utils
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.Exception: Unsupported binding form: 1111, compiling:(com/mycompany/resources/mytool.clj:198:1)
                    java.lang.Exception: Unsupported binding form: 1111
                                        ......

Impl way 2:
(ns com.mycompany.resources.tools

   (:require [com.mycompany.protocols.tools :as proto]))

(deftype MyTool [config]
   proto/Tool

(test-ov
   [this user-id]
       1111 )

(test-ov
   [this]
      (test-ov this nil))

......

Error I got
    LOAD FAILURE for com.mycompany.test.myservice.resources.utils
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: test-ov in this context, compiling:(com/mycompany/myservice/resources/mytool.clj:335:6)
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: test-ov in this context

                                            ......

So how to call the override function from the "orginal" function with protocol defined? Please help. Thanks.

According to the documentation of defprotocol, the second approach is the correct one:
(deftype MyTool [config]
   proto/Tool
   (test-ov [this user-id] 1111)
   (test-ov [this] (test-ov this nil)))

The problem is with the invocation of (test-ov this nil) because the symbol test-ov is unknown in this context. To resolve it, either write (proto/test-ov this nil) or explicitly refer the var in the require form: (:require [com.mycompany.protocols.tools :as proto :refer [test-ov])

This is the right answer, but only explains the second error message. The first error comes because the compiler sees ([this user-id] 1111 ) as the arglist for the testov function, and 1111 is not a meaningful argument declaration.

@erdos, I changed [com.mycompany.protocols.tools :as proto] to [com.mycompany.protocols.tools :as proto :refer [test-ov]], and go with the approach you mentioned. But I got error "clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Function test-ov in protocol Tool was redefined. Specify all arities in single definition., ......"
